# Проблема с viewport

Tags: html, css, viewport

На странице

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1440">
```

На всех разрешениях все в порядке, кроме — 320px. На этом разрешении сайт не по ширине экрана, соответственно появляется горизонтальный скролл, как решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Смотреть и проверять саму верстку, вероятно что-то не влазит в 320px

Comment: @HamSter с версткой все в порядке ширина страницы правильная, но если разрешение экрана меньше 360px появляется скрол

Comment: @StanislavNasonov, если появляется скролл, значит, с вёрсткой не всё в порядке. Приведите здесь код страницы